# how to send array of array using JSON

Tags: php, json

i have a function which brings me some data from database and posts to my client. At the moment it sends data as a normal array(output is something like MyArray (a,b,c,d..)), but i want it to be MyArray (a(b,c,d)).. As like Castegory(Name, ID, Order..).. Can anyone please Help..Here is my code for already used version

```
public function get_button_template()
    {
        $this->q = "SELECT * FROM button_template ORDER BY order_number ASC";
        $this->r = mysql_query($this->q);
        if(mysql_num_rows($this->r) > 0)
        {        
            while($this->f = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->r))
            {
                $this->buttons[$this->i]["ID"] = $this->f["ID"];          
                $this->buttons[$this->i]["name"] = $this->f["button_name"];               
                $this->buttons[$this->i]["category"] = $this->f["button_category"];
                $this->buttons[$this->i]["order_number"] = $this->f["order_number"]; 
                $this->i++;
            }
        }
        return $this->buttons;
    }
```

**EDIT** A little öore detail please..
when i parsed this i get something like this:

`"Vaule"( "Key1": "Value1" "Key2": "Value2" .`

But what i want is omething like

```
 `"Category0":( "Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2" . ) 

"Category1":( "Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2" . )..`
```

How can i send a multidimentional array with key-value pairs?

Comment: just pass your array to json_encode. there's no practical limit to how deeply you nest your arrays.

Comment: @MarcB I think he wants to transform his array as well.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @tereško I'm a beginner with PHP bro:) i will step as far as i can.. Now, can you please my question, from edit?

Comment: no , i will not *please your question* ... that sounds nasty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change how you build the array. If you want to group by category:

**Edit**

Code changed to create numbered categories using a name => key map.

```
$category_map = array(); $cat_nr = 0;
while ($this->f = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->r)) {
    if (!isset($category_map[$this->f["button_category"]])) {
        $category_key = "Category{$cat_nr}";
        $category_map[$this->f["button_category"]] = $category_key;
        ++$cat_nr;
    } else {
        $category_key = $category_map[$this->f["button_category"]];
    }
    $this->buttons[$category_key]][] = array(
        'category' => $this->f["button_category"],
        "ID" => $this->f["ID"],
        "name" => $this->f["button_name"],
        "order_number" => $this->f["order_number"],
    );
    $this->i++;
}
```

This produces an array like:

```
<category 1>: [
    (CatName1, Id1, name1, ordernr1)
    (CatName1, Id2, name2, ordernr2)
],
<category 2>: [
    (CatName2, Id3, name3, ordernr3)
    (CatName2, Id4, name4, ordernr4)
]
```

Then use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on the end-result.

Btw, not sure why you store those buttons inside the object itself ;-)

Comment: I'm making a Web Service application for iOS(ipad), i send buttons for each user from server, i will group the buttons on client side(ipad) with for categories. And i'm not so experienced with programming, i may have some problem with my design of objects, communication with server&polling data ect.. Thanks for your answer

Comment: when i parsed this i get something like this:
"Vaule"(
"Key1": "Value1"
"Key2": "Value2"
.
But what i want is omething like 
"Category0":(

"Key1": "Value1"
"Key2": "Value2"
.
)
"Category1":(
"Key1": "Value1"
"Key2": "Value2"
.
).. How can i send a multidimentional array with key-value pairs?

Comment: @ilis What's `Vaule`? Where does that come from? What's the input?

Comment: for example, i get the output of each inner loop(the elements of every category) as:

 3 =         (
                        {
                ID = 4;
                name = Yemekler;
                "order_number" = 12;
            }
        );
        serf =         (
                        {
                ID = 51;
                name = serf;
                "order_number" = 4;
            }
        );
Here "3" and "serf" are the names of categories.. i want to get them as: "Category0":"1"... "Category1":"serf"..

Comment: @ilis I don't understand what you want ... something like this? http://codepad.org/m16pqAS6

Comment: @ilis updated the answer; btw, it's not nice to unaccept an answer just to force someone to update it to your changed question :)

Comment: Thanks for answer please believe me that was not my aim, from PHP chat room someone said that since you have accepted the answer your question seems answered so you will not be answered so shortly, and i re-checked your answer. I would accept again after some answer(any answer.).. I did this because i didnt want to ask a new question on the same topic. Really sorry for that

Comment: @ilis Just a comment would have been enough in this case, it's common courtesy to allow someone to adjust their answer (even if it was already accepted). In any case, like I said, I've updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: it works great. I have some headache with parsing it on Objective C side now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Use json_encode function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 ] )
```