# How to parse nested JSON arrays in Objective C

Tags: php, objective-c, arrays, json, parsing

I have [this](http://pastebin.com/q3WuveXD) JSON tree and I need to group the arrays by category key. (In this example,: "","1","2","3" and "serf" are value names for categories.) I'm serializing JSON using NSJSONSerialization but can't parse it the way I want to. Here is some of my code:

```
NSData *data2=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2];
result2=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data2
                                        options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                          error: nil];
NSLog(@"button data: %@", result2);
for (NSDictionary *strh in [result2 objectForKey:@"template"]) {
    //the json struct above is called result2 here
    //now i need to parse any category with their names..           
}
```

**Related:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580300/how-to-send-array-of-array-using-json) is my question about how to create multidimentional arrays with key-value matching in PHP.

Comment: What is the actual problem? "but can't parse it the way I want to" -- what is the result you want, and what is the result you're getting?

Comment: @Felixyz the result i want is to reach objects over names. for example
to be able to read button data from categories

Comment: Without seeing the structure of result2, it's hard to help you.  What are these categories you're talking about?

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/JbQ7dmPg) it is. I have shared the link at the beginning of the question

Comment: take a look at this please: http://pastebin.com/q3WuveXD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the output, you have a dictionary with a key called `template` and a key called `version`.  the object for the key `template` is itself a dictionary containing keys for your categories.  The following code:

```
id foo = [[result2 objectForKey: @"template"] objectForKey: @""];
```

will set `foo` to an array containing the items with id's 52, 19, 2, 22.

Categories 1, 2 ,3 are more tricky because it's not obvious whether the keys are numbers or strings.  They are probably strings, since keys in JSON have to be strings, so

```
id bar = [[result2 objectForKey: @"template"] objectForKey: @"1"];
```

will set `bar` to an array containing the items with id's 28, 1, 25.

Comment: i'm a little confused about naming(i write myself the PHP side) but i can change. i tried somthing like this but couldnt get any result.